# cs50 - pset2 - Can't pass the check

Tags: c, cs50

I just finished writing the code and it checks mostly right except 2 points:

```
:( encrypts all alphabetic characters using DWUSXNPQKEGCZFJBTLYROHIAVM as key
    output not valid ASCII text

:( handles invalid characters in key
    timed out while waiting for program to exit
```

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    int i = 0, z, n = 0;
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./substitution key\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (strlen(argv[1]) != 26)
    {
        printf("Key must contain 26 characters.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    while (n < strlen(argv[1]))
    {
        if ((argv[1][i] > '@' && argv[1][i] < '[') || (argv[1][i] > '`' && argv[1][i] < '{'))
        {
            n++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Key must only contain alphabetic characters.\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
    {
        for (n = 0; n < strlen(argv[1]); n++)
        {
            if (tolower(argv[1][i]) == tolower(argv[1][n]) && i != n)
            {
                printf("Key must not contain repeated characters.\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    string s = get_string("plaintext: ");
    char f[strlen(s)];
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)
    {
        if ((s[i] > '@' && s[i] < '[') || (s[i] > '`' && s[i] < '{'))
        {
            if (isupper(s[i]))
            {
                z = s[i] - 65;
                f[i] = toupper(argv[1][z]);
            }
            else if (islower(s[i]))
            {
                z = s[i] - 97;
                f[i] = tolower(argv[1][z]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            f[i] = s[i];
        }
    }
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (i = 0; i < strlen(f); i++)
    {
        printf("%c" , f[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

So I was wondering where I went wrong since I am still new to C.

Comment: Me too. Where do you think the problem is? Have you stepped through in a debugger?

Comment: Why do your refer to `argv[1]` all the time in a loop that is apparently about `n`? `char f[strlen(s)];` -- **DO NOT** forget the NUL terminator. It's `strlen(s) + 1`.

Comment: This code *urgently* needs to be broken down into smaller, more understandable, **more easily tested** functions.

Comment: `char f[strlen(s)];` --> `char f[strlen(s) + 1];` and write a string terminator too.

Comment: Aside: instead of `z = s[i] - 65;` use `z = s[i] - 'A'` and for `z = s[i] - 97;` use `z = s[i] - 'a';`. Avoid magic numbers, which are hard to read and maintain, and can easily make mistakes. I can never remember the exact ASCII value for say `z`, so don't make readers look it up to see if you have the right value. Use `'z'`.

Comment: @tadman Insightful question, but I think you dropped a `[i]` in there.

Comment: @Yunnosch That too. I mean it's always looking at `argv[1][i]` but never `argv[n][i]` as I'd expect.

Comment: There are two effective ways to find what's wrong. The correct way is to use a debugger: set it up, add breakpoints, run, print variables step through or add more breakpoints, and determine where the values don't match what you expect, and that's usually the problem. The other way is what everyone actually does: add print/log statements, run, get confused about what's happening, add and remove print statements, suddenly realise what's wrong for unrelated reasons, and fix it.

Comment: @tadman I corrected the ones you mentioned but I don't understand why  n  matter in argv[n][i] as i will always be using the key which is always in 1.

Comment: @JohnBayko tried doing so in multiple occasions but I can't still figure it out

Comment: @Hypor14 Your first trouble is the `while` loop, but first you can simplify things by assigning `char const * const key = argv[1];` just after you check `argc` (the `const` are optional since you're learing, but useful). That could be a `for` loop, but ignoring that, the problem is `while (n < ...) { if key[i] > ...) {n++;} ...`. You're scanning using `n`, but indexing using `i`. Use one or the other in both places.

Comment: What is `n` doing? Why are you comparing the same spot in a string?

Comment: @tadman I am checking every character in the string to see if they are repeated or not ,couldn't think of better way

Comment: A) Use a function with a descriptive name, like `check_repeats()` B) Test that this function works *before* integrating it in other code. C) If you have variables like `n`, they're usually used in the intermediate `if` test, but you're not doing that here.

Comment: Easy way to test for repeats: Sort the string's characters, as a string is just an array and you can trivially `qsort()` it, and then look for repeated characters. This is way faster than comparing every character with every other character, and as a bonus, is a lot more readable. You could also use a bitmask, there's only 26 letters and a 32-bit int can easily accommodate that, to keep track of "used" letters.

Comment: @Hypor14 Your second problem was pointed out above, but maybe not clearly if you're stil new to C. A string like `"ok"` (2 characters) is stored as `{'o,'k,'\0'}` (3 bytes). `strlen()` only counts the first 2 bytes. Add 1 for both the array `f[]` and the `for` loop.

Comment: @Hypor14 There are other issues that you just learn from experience. For example `strlen()` works by actually counting the letters each time. Since the string length doesn't change, you get the length once and store it in a variable. Also, `ctype.h` has useful functions like `isalpha()` , and `string.h` has functions like `index()` to search for a character in a string. Those would simplify your code a lot.

Comment: Encoding each character: `for (i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++)`... No. This is using the length of the "key", not the length of the plaintext being enciphered... This code likely producing all sorts of UB..

Comment: It worked now and I understand my various mistakes.
thanks for your help guys.

Comment: @JohnBayko: the standard C version of `<string.h>` does not provide `index()` but provides `strchr()` for the same job.  Using `index()` instead is archaic.